# Why am I getting an 'invalid frame header' error with Socket.IO and PeerJS?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

[I have looked for answers but couldn't fix it. anybody have a solution for this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZKuz.png)

I have tried to add allowIO3 while setting up my io server
const io = new Server(server, {
cors: {
origin: "http://localhost:3000",
methods: ["GET", "POST"],
transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
credentials: true
},
allowEIO3: true
})
on the server side to help but still get the same error